# Help justifying unique 2n-1 sum pairs as (2n-1, {3, 5,...,2n-3,2n-1})

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, permutations, multisets

Need help for a long proof I am doing. I need to justify that if I examine the set of {Odd+Odd}, the unique pairs exist if I utilize {2n-1, {3,5...,2n-3,2n-1})

If we have:

- 3       5       7       9       11

3 (3,3)  (3,5)   (3,7)   (3,9)   (3,11)

5 (5,3)  (5,5)   (5,7)   (5,9)   (5,11)

7 (7,3)  (7,5)   (7,7)   (7,9)   (7,11)

9 (9,3)  (9,5)   (9,7)   (9,9)   (9,11)

11(11,3) (11,5)  (11,7) (11,9)  (11,11)

The unique sets are obvious as there's a line of reflection around (3,3); (5,5); (2n-1,2n-1). Thus unique sets are (3,3); (5,3), (5,5), (7,3), (7,5), (7,7), (9,3)... (9,9), (11,3)... (11,11)...

But I want the longer proof to be as complete as possible. What are my options here? Is there  a stars and bars equation? Or a simple binomial expansion rule?

Thanks.

I apologize for weird formatting. I'm on my phone and this is urgent.

Comment: Please use [$\LaTeX$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting your post. Follow the link and then [*edit your question*](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1578703/edit). And be sure about the tags you are using.

Comment: Darn, I'm not by a computer. It's not possible to get away with it this one time? My apologies.

Comment: Ok, you need not worry much. There are [*other great editors*](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/49/copy-editor) in this site.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what actually you need? Please *explain*. Else others will close this post as off-topic.

Comment: I need to justify that (3,3); (5,3); (5,5), (7,3), (7,5), (7,7) are the unique odd pairs that sum to even numbers. (5,7) for example is not unique because it is the same as (7,5). All unique pairs are generated by (2n-1,3) to (2n-1,2n-1) for each n.

Comment: You're on a phone and this is urgent ? It really doesn't sound too good.

Comment: There's no exam. I'm working on a goldbach's solution and need a working copy in hand. I been working on this for months and the concepts I know inside out Im just unfamiliar with explaining a justification for my approach. The results of the approach are quite evidenced. Just looking for a platform to finish writing my thesis ddrsft. Do people actually post here during an exam or something? Am impressed if they do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way in which an ordered pair of odd numbers could be *non*-unique is by inversion, i.e., $a\neq b$ and both $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ are counted. Thus, as you suggest correctly, then number of equivalence classes under the equivalence relation defined by inversion is equal to $k(k+1)/2$ where $k$ is the number of candidates that you started with. In your example $k=n-1,$ but is there any specific reason why you left the odd number $1$ out?

Comment: I'm working with primes and one is irrelevant and detracts from the focus. I'm working on goldbachs conjecture and this is the process of analysis: where a and b are odd; (a,b) must be in form (a,b <=a); and a and b cannot equal 1. I'm treating it as if a+(b=1) would be an irrelevant identity sum to 2N. It should be sufficient to just limit the values, putting a constraint that a and/or b cannot equal 1?

Comment: the inversion would be defined as n (n-1)/2 if we replace k with n in the inversion equivalence relation? And it is k=n-1 because we exclude 1? Wow. Much simpler than expected. I was using unique remainders of modulo operations.

Comment: isn't k=(n+1)/2? Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you enumerate the odd numbers like $3,5,\ldots,2n-3,2n-1$ then their total number is $n-1.$ The halving is taken care of by your writing $2n.$

Comment: So. I've used the justification of the equivalence relation to validate my unique pairs argument. Now say I then take the pairs and then list their sums as (a+b),b. Can you help me justify the formula for {b}? I realize when (a+b)/2=even, {b}={3,5,7....(a+b)-2)/2)} and when (a+b)/2=odd, {b}={3,5,7....(a+b)/2)}. So when a+b=12 the set of b is {3,5} and when a+b=14 the set of b is {3,5,7}. Thanks!

Comment: The number of possible values of $b$ for a *fixed* even sum $2c=a+b$ where $a$ and $b$ are odd integers greater than 1 and $a\geq b$ is the number of odd integers between 3 and $c.$ If $c$ is even then it is $c/2-1,$ if $c$ is odd then it is $c/2-0.5.$

Comment: Now what would be the method of approach for analyzing the trends across (a+b),b pairs, such that it is in a justifiable form. Let me explain via example using pair (20,5). The first a+b value is 6 and let's call this column A. 20 would be column H and 5 would be row 2. (20,5)=Cell H2. Now I want to examine vertical (H3-H2-H1) horizontal(G2-H2-I2) and diagonal trends (G1-H2-I3; I1,H2,G3). How do I equate all this under a common variable? Thanks so much!

Comment: Justpassingby, As I'm submitting a paper can you shoot me your name via email so I can properly credit you? It may seem banal I'm asking all these questions to submit a paper, but it's because I am a completionist. My email is jm3437@nyu.edu

Comment: @Dr Jason M Thanks doc but I strictly separate my activity on SE from my professional work - if you want to mention this conversation call it "a helpful comment by an anonymous stackexchange user" :-) But tell us here when it is published!